# Using functions in a dll in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, name-decoration

I have created a dll in c++ using __declspec(dllexport) before class name. Now when i try to use it in another c++ program it crashes in between. When i debugged it i found that the function pointer is not initialized at all. help me plz.

```
using namespace std;

typedef void (*func)();

int main()

{

    func funcpointer;
    HINSTANCE xyz = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\extra\\dll\\dlls\\debug\\random.dll"));
    funcpointer = (func)GetProcAddress(xyz,"get it");
    funcpointer();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you used `__declspec(dllexport)` on a class, but are trying to import a function. If you export a class that way, you can pretty much only import it using `__declspec(dllimport)`, you can't use `GetProcAddress`. If you used `__declspec(dllexport)` on a function, the name is likely decorated and you'll have to use the decorated name in the call to `GetProcAddress` (use depends.exe or something to see what the decorated name is).

Comment: What exactly is "get it" ? I cannot be name of exported function.

Comment: @Ajay: why not? I don't see a rule that forbids it. You'd have to use a DEF file, though.

Comment: May be, but I haven't seen any till date!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use `DUMPBIN /EXPORTS yourdll.dll` to see if the function you expect to be exported is actually exported and its *exact* name. If you find the name "mangled" you probably need to declare the function as `extern "C"`. Once you have determined the name the way you go is correct. Check also the `HINSTANCE xyz` became not null after loading the library. If null you robably don't reach the dll ( not in the search path ) or for some reason it can't load for example because some dependencies are missing.

Comment: hi felice. As you suggested me I used DUMPBIN and also stepped into the code. When I reached  HINSTANCE initiatialization I got this in auto window   -                                               xyz 0x10000000 {unused=9460301 } HINSTANCE__ * unused 9460301 int

Comment: @Apoorva sahay Having 0x1000000 means that is ok since is the deafult load address for a dll and means the dll loads properly. su just check for the name.

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of "get it" you should write the name of the function you want to retrieve.
2. You should have not only dllexport, but also the whole dllexport/dllimport definition in the retrieved function's header file:

   ```
   #if defined DLL_EXPORT   
   #define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)
   #else
   #define DECLDIR __declspec(dllimport)
   #endif

   extern "C"
   {
      DECLDIR void foo();
   }
   ```

You can read the [DLL Tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

When you export your function use extern "C" fndecl. This will help to get an undecorated name or use a def-file. To check the name of the exported function use the tool [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (depends.exe).

If you have a C++ class I would advise you to link to the DLL. Using GetProcAddress it would be a pain to use a C++ class.

This link could also be interesting for you if you are new to DLLs:
[Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Has this tool `depends.exe` been removed from VS2010 package? It seems I can find it in VC6, but cannot in VS2010. Although `dumpbin` can do the job but it's not so convenient as `depends.exe`.

Comment: hey frast thanx for the expert comments. But can you refer me any good tutorial or ebook or amy material that may help me in getting good knowledge in dll and c++.

Comment: I like learning from references. If you do too then the following links may be of help:  

[Dynamic-Link Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682589(v=vs.85).aspx)  

[Linking an Executable to a DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I added a link to a walkthrough.

Comment: Thanx Frast, but i want to ask whether extern "C" will work even for class also.